# How to clone an instance of oneself , like Chromium does?

Tags: c++, singleton, instance

When i launch chromium again when it's already started , i can see the following:

> %> chromium-browser
>   Created new window in existing browser session.

Is there any general way in C++ to do a similar thing ? Or is it like just "new" function in C++ , simply clone another object ? I'm confused.

Comment: What makes you think there's anything being cloned? Cloning suggests there was once one thing, and now there is a second, identical copy of it. That's not what you describe. To clone a browser instance would mean you get a second set of tabs, the same add those in the first browser window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is nothing at all like "new" in C++: it's at a vastly higher level. When the new process is started, it looks for an existing process, and if it finds one, it sends it a command to create a new window, then exits. The syntax and nature of that command is specific to the application (or application framework), as is the mechanism by which an existing instance is found.

Comment: More details: one common way to do that is to store the PID of the running process somewhere (maybe in /tmp/my_app_name). When the application is relaunched, it looks in this location for a PID, and contacts the associated process.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to use fork() system call to create a new process identical to the parent process. The new process would have a different process id(PID). In the case of Chrome browser also, if you look at task manager (Windows) or the output of 'ps' command (Linux), you can see that once you open a new tab, it is a new process with new PID.

The following link would be useful for understanding fork()

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html